# What clothes does the doctor change into the first time he is in the confession dial?

Tags: doctor-who

The doctor, when cornered by the veil for the first time (in that time loop) jumps through the window after throwing the chair out of it to break the glass. However, he has a safe landing because there is water at the bottom in which there are skulls of his previous versions. Then, we see the doctor enter a room where clothes identical to the ones he is wearing are kept. So he changes into them leaving his damp clothes on the same spot which would be dry by the time the next version of the doctor arrives, soaking wet. 
My question is -  **what clothes does the first version of the doctor wear?**
Do we assume that the confession dial had a set of clothes in that room different from the 12th doctor’s outfit? If so, why doesn’t the room reset and have that different outfit for every version? 
Is this a plot hole?

Comment: Once he figured out what was going on, he likely left his first set behind.

Comment: Similar questions: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/109185/18979 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/174355/18979

Comment: What if the first time around he also left his wet clothes there and changed into......well, nothing. Or a towel or something. The clothes would be dry for the next version.

Comment: @amflare how can the first version of the doctor figure out what’s going on if he’s the first version out of the teleportation device ? Also,each version figures out what’s going on after they have left that room